# Create a C++ program that processes incoming calls on a phone-line (land-line)

Tags: c++, windows, networking, phone-call

For some time now I've been tossing around what I think is am awesome idea: I want to write essentially a C++ phone server to handle all of my incoming calls on a land-line.  I'll have a white-list (yay never having to worry about telemarketers ever again!), a black-list, and will be able to access my phone using my gaming headset, allowing me to make/answer calls while I'm gaming or whatever.  In the future I'd also like to hook it up to a gui and make it have pop-ups and other cool features.

The problem is, I have no idea where to start.  I'm familiar enough with C++, but have no idea how to go about doing anything with a phone-line.  I can plug a phone-line into my computer, but I have no idea how to get my program to be able to use that connection.  There's WinSock2 for being able to use my ethernet connection,  is there something similar I'd be able to use to use the phone line?  As it's using the same ethernet jack, I wonder if it's even possible to use WinSock2 to use the phone-line?

I saw this post, which wasn't particularly helpful: [stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443865/c-api-for-understanding-tone-signals-on-a-phone-line) , which points out Dual-tone multi-frequency signaling.  I stumbled across this site: [link](http://www.mathworks.com/products/signal/demos.html?file=/products/demos/shipping/signal/dtmfdemo.html), but isn't really going to help me get started.

So I was wondering, is there some sort of library out there that would allow me to tap into a phone-line that's connected to my computer? Is there a standard somewhere out there concerning phone-lines and what the different combinations of tone's mean?  Can anyone here help get me started?  I realize it's somewhat of a big undertaking, so any push in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

[Update:]
I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2555034/free-modem-dialer), which is a step in the right direction, but I'm not sure yet if it helps me (I need to go to bed, and will take a look at it in the morning).  I did see mention of a Microsoft Telephony API though, I'll try doing more research on that tomorrow.

Comment: This is going to be difficult because most modems nowadays do not ship with voice decoding hardware; only with the data transmission hardware. If you've got a voice modem go ahead but I think it's quite unlikely that you do.

Comment: Are you sure the phone line "[uses] the same ethernet jack" as your network connection? I'm not sure about where you live, but my phones are RJ11 and my Ethernet is RJ45. See the [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Registered_jack).

Comment: @Sedate Alien I'm just talking about the port in my computer, I know they're different lines.

Comment: What do you mean by "port"? The physical jack (i.e. hole) or something else? The physical jacks are different on the (old) laptops around my house.

Comment: @Sedate Alien Not on my desktop; I'm using a Gigabyte EX58 UD5 motherboard, and both the phone line and my ethernet cord plug into the same socket (physical jack, whatever! am I speaking Klingon or something? ;P ). So I guess on other computers I can't expect the same, alright, so they definitely are treated differently.

Comment: I used an old zoom modem external serial but capable of voice; transmits and receives raw data--a few codecs all dependent upon configuration with AT commands.  Easy as pie to write a small script I suppose or use existing software like `vgetty` or `mgetty` with a modem.  See also http://www.linuxtoys.org/answer/answering_machine.html

Answer (score 3):

If working with MS products is not an absolute necessity, you might also consider taking a shot at [Asterisk](http://www.digium.com/en/). This is an open-source PBX (in software) that allows development on Linux, Windows (emulated) and Mac. At the company where I work, we use it for implementing small-scale exchanges, about a 100 lines or so. It also interfaces well with VoIP and allows a whole host of protocols. I have developed scripts and programs in C++ that work on voice packets in real-time, and so far, my experience has been good. As for your stated use-case of blocking telemarketers etc., this would be a very good fit. Check out further details [here](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk).

Answer (score 0):

After doing more research, having one link lead to another link, and coming up with new search terms, I stumbled across this site that looks like it could kick me off using the Windows Telephony API in C++: [link](http://www.julmar.com/tapi/).  This link includes open source c++ samples showing how to do the basics of what this question asks, I'll just have to test to see if they actually still work.

This is only the beginning of my research, so I'll keep you posted on any other findings.  If anyone else is knowledgeable in this area, please still feel free to drop me information on what I want to accomplish.